# Prime stepping stones

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, primes

Start by placing number $1$ anywhere on an infinite square grid. Now place numbers $2, 3, 4, \ldots, K$ in order. A number $k$ can be placed if the following rules hold:

- It must be adjacent (horizontally or vertically) to the previous number $k-1$.
- It must have at least one neighbour (horizontally or vertically) number $m$ already placed such that $k+m$ is prime. Note that $m$ can be $k-1$.

What is the largest number $K$ that you can place? You can use a computer if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found with the assistance of a computer program. It couldn't find anything larger so I think this is an upper bound.

> 47
>
> ```
>                    1  6  7
>          31 30 29  2  5  8  9
> 47 42 41 32 27 28  3  4 11 10
> 46 43 40 33 26 15 14 13 12
> 45 44 39 34 25 16 17 18
>       38 35 24 23 20 19
>       37 36    22 21
> ```

Comment: Great work. Does your program do an exhaustive search?

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky yes, source code here: https://pastebin.com/Nup7qB4J it does a brute force search up to N == 100 on a 100 by 100 grid with 1 starting in the center, but since the best we've found is < 100 / 2, it should be exhaustive

Comment: Can you please include the source code in your answer? Also, welcome to Puzzling!

Answer (score 1):

I can do

> 43
>  
>  which is about the limit of what I'm willing to do manually ;-)
>
> ```
>        37 36 31 30 27 26 25 24
>  42 41 38 35 32 29 28 15 16 23 22
>  43 40 39 34 33 12 13 14 17 20 21
>              10 11  4  3 18 19
>               9  8  5  2  1
>                  7  6
> ```

Comment: This is a great start Paul! I wonder how far can we push this? Perhaps there is no limit to $K$?